# Is there is a way to pop my screen automatically?

Tags: flutter

In my app ["see the structure image"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDHVT.jpg) I use a wrapper to navigate the StartUp page or HomePage/NewsFeed page. On the startup page, I have 2 options 1. User Login 2. Volunteer Login. When I use any of these pages to log in its successful to login but page changes in the background. My login page doesn't pop out. I use `Navigator.of(context).pop()` but nothing works

Main Page code

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  // This widget is the root of This application.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: Authentication().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData().copyWith(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0XFF00B8A9),
          canvasColor: Color(0XFF00B8A9),
          cursorColor: Color(0XFF00B8A9),
        ),
        initialRoute: Wrapper.id,

        routes: {
          Wrapper.id: (context) => Wrapper(),
          StartUpScreen.id: (context) => StartUpScreen(),
          SignIn.id: (context) => SignIn(),
          VolunteerLogin.id: (context) => VolunteerLogin(),
          Registration.id: (context) => Registration(),
          VolunteerHome.id: (context) => VolunteerHome(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Wrapper Page Code

```
  class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {

  static String id = "Wrapper";


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // Check if the user login or not and based on condition send him to different screen
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    if(user == null){
      return StartUpScreen();
    }else{
      return NewsFeed();
    }
  }
}
```

StartUp page code

```
class StartUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  static String id = "Start_Up_Screen";

  @override
  _StartUpScreenState createState() => _StartUpScreenState();
}

class _StartUpScreenState extends State<StartUpScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, SignIn.id);
                  },
                  child: ReusableButton(
                    containerColor: kPrimaryButtonColor,
                    buttonChild: Text(
                      "User Login",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 40.0,
                  width: 30.0,
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () =>
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, VolunteerHome.id),
                  child: ReusableButton(
                    containerColor: kSOSButtonColor,
                    buttonChild: Text(
                      "Volunteer Login",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Login Page code

```
class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {

  static String id = "Sign_In";

  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {

  Authentication _authentication = Authentication();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  // text field state
  String email = '';
  String password = '';


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          autovalidate: true,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                decoration: kInputFormFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'email'),
                validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Enter an email' : null,
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() => email = val);
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: kInputFormFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'password'),
                obscureText: true,
                validator: (val) => val.length < 6 ? 'Enter a password 6+ chars long' : null,
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() => password = val);
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0),

              RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.pink[400],
                child: Text(
                  'Sign In',
                  style: TextStyle(color: kPrimaryButtonColor),
                ),
                onPressed: () async {
                  await _authentication.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you use `Navigator.of(context).pop()` I see you using `Navigator.pushNamed(context, routeName);` which would be why your screen is not popping off try changing this too.

```
  Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed(routeName)
```

If you have tried this already let me know and I will try and help you further.

Comment: Not worked :(

Please see my code video here - [link](https://www.loom.com/share/c6d70926a51c4400973a9d5e04127233)

 Also, see my app screen record here - [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hJQuSlq8-BBBO74H-CJVqRSc6E13Xxum/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: in what screen transition are you trying too pop the login screen you want to never be able to go back to login screen right?

Comment: When I input email and pass in my login screen and press login button the screen still stays in. And when I press back button the login screen pop and I can see the newsfeed screen. My problem is when I tap on the login button on the login screen after successful login my newsfeed screen should show. But its not automatically navigate.

Comment: if you put a print statement right after ```AuthResult``` right before your the if statement and see what ```authResults``` is returning what do you get

Comment: Are you still haviing this issue

Comment: No. I solved it by using `Navigator.pop(SignIn.id)`

Comment: oh you fixed it thats good and you must have misunderstood me because that is what I was suggesting you do from the beginning happy coding